# Can I use Travis-CI with a Tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter, travis-ci

I'd like to use Travis-CI for a program I'm making in Tkinter, but I having trouble getting my build to pass.

Example program **TravisTest.py**:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        root.title('TEST')
        
        self.Hi = tk.Label(self, text="Hi!")
        self.Hi.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

**.travis.yml**:

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.5"
  - "3.6"
dist: xenial
services:
  - xvfb
script: python TravisTest.py
```

The program seems to start fine, but since it doesn't exit on its own, the build just sits for 10 minutes before being timed out.

> $ python TravisTest.py
>
> No output has been received in the last 10m0s,
> this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the
> build itself.
>
> Check the details on how to adjust your build
> configuration on:
> https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received
>
> The build has been terminated

Do I need to add some Travis-CI specific test cases to my code, to exit on its own? Or should I just not be using Travis-CI for something like this?

Comment: What are you *expecting* to happen here? As you say, the program never exits on its own, hence the error from Travis after ten minutes. Are you just trying to check that it *can* start?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm expecting it to fail because of the loop, but I was wondering what I could change to work around that. I wasn't aware of `update` instead of `mainloop`, which solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

root.mainloop() runs the event loop until something stops it.  Delete it, replace it with `root.update()` and maybe `root.update_idletasks()` to make sure all gui actions are done, or arrange for it to be stopped by adding something like `root.after(10, root.quit)`

The python test suite has gui tests for tkinter, IDLE, and turtle.  Using xvfb, they are run on Windows (Appveyor), Linux (Travis), and Mac (MS Azure, which also run tests on Windows and Linux).   The script is the equivalent of `python -m test`, which runs all test.test_xyz modules.  Stdlib modules are not run as 'main'.

The IDLE tests in test_idle do not run mainloop().  This is currently avoided by, among other things, not running idlelib.pyshell.main(), which contains the main mainloop() call.  (pyshell.main should be refactored to remove most everything else to separate functions that can be tested without calling mainloop().)  IDLE tests that create widgets use invoke, generate_event, update and, for clean exits, update_idletasks.  The actual tests are in idlelib.idle_test.test_*.  There is a lot of hard-won knowledge about testing a tkinter app contained therein.  For testing non-gui parts of the code, mock widgets help.

Comment: I realized that replacing mainloop makes my exe from pyinstaller quit right after launching. It makes sense, but I was hoping for a solution that would allow both pyinstaller and Travis-CI to work without having to change code in between. I ended up using `if 'TRAVIS' in os.environ:` to check the environment, but I feel it's kind of sacrilegious to use different code in the test environment.

Comment: If you use Travis to run a module, without alteration or addition for the test, it will test that the module compiles without syntax error, that module level code runs, and that calls to nested code run.  'Running' mostly means that arguments to calls are minimally acceptible.  If, for instance, your code had `MainApplication(tk)` or `.pack(xyz='joker')`, this minimal test would fail.  To go further, and test that results are 'correct', you must add test code either in the module or a separate test module.  GUI code must also be checked by eye.